# Odd text before ":" in Terminal

Tags: macos, mac

In Terminal.app I have a text prompt like the following

```
rover-205-89:Documents username$
```

What is the "rover-205-89"? I thought it was my computer name but I looked under System Preferences > Sharing and that isn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is your computer's **hostname**. In Terminal type the command `hostname` and that is what you'll see. You can change the host name with the command `sudo scutil --set HostName desired-host-name`. There are some networking scenarios where this won't permanently fix the problem, though. (e.g. [OS X assumes hostname of other network computer: how to prevent this?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23848/os-x-assumes-hostname-of-other-network-computer-how-to-prevent-this)). It happens with my machine at work (on a Windows domain). Aside from being a little disconcerting, there are no functional repercussions that I've experienced.

Comment: Ok cause I noticed it happen when I joined a network,